# How to wait for an async event to finish before closing the application?

Tags: c#

I am building a crawler and I am using [aBot](https://code.google.com/p/abot/) to do it. It is a very nice system :)
During the development I found an issue that is more related to how I want to build my crawler than the aBot project itself, but I hope you can help me.

When setting a crawler, I specify the method to be called when the crawling is complete, there is sync and async options.

```
        crawler.PageCrawlCompleted += crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted;
        crawler.PageCrawlCompletedAsync += crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted;
```

I would like to use the async one because then I would be crawling another url while processing the older one. This works fine until I crawl the last url.
When I crawl the last one, I call the completeAsync method and my crawler is done working, so it finishes and the program is closed without finishing processing the _ProcessPageCrawlComplete method entirely, so I cannot guarantee that the last url will be processed.

Is there any way I can wait for this last event to finish before closing the application? Is this a design flaw?

Edit: I forgot to mention: I do have access to the crawler code. My current workaround is: if the link is the last one to be processed, create a WaitHandle and wait for it to complete. Sound a bit messy, though...

Comment: This may be over simplistic, but couldn't you simply keep a count of the open crawlers, decrementing that count when you hit the complete method, and not close the app until that count is 0?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the crawler will finish the "crawl" when it gets the last response for the last page. So it may happen the the crawler is closed, but the last result is still being processed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) can be one solution:

In your calling method:

```
//Declare the reset event
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

//Call the async method and subscribe to the event 
crawler.PageCrawlCompletedAsync += crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted;

//The application will wait here until the mre is set.
mre.WaitOne();
```

In your event handler:

```
private void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted(...)
{
   ....
   mre.Set();
}
```

Another approach can be the [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Suppose you need to crawl 10 pages:

```
CountdownEvent countdown = new CountdownEvent (10);

//Subscribe to the event 
crawler.PageCrawlCompletedAsync += crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted;

//Call 10 time the async method
....

//Wait for all events to complete
countdown.Wait();
```

In the handler:

```
private void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted(...)
{
    ....
   mre.Signal();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alberto it seems a nice approach, I will research about it. But if I call the crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted 10 times, finishing the first processing will set the ManualResetEvent and then the last one will not be required to finish the application. Is this statement correct?

Comment: You should call mre.Set() only in the last event... I added another approach in the answer.